# Should sendto block when eth linkndown? Vxworks 6.9

Tags: sockets, vxworks

When disconnecting the eth cable while periodically calling sendto on a udp socket, caller task blocks. Once link is back up, it is released. If the link is already down before transmitting, sendto does not block.
Is this the expected behavior of the net stack? Shouldnt the stack be robust enough to detect link down and abort the transmission  or even just have a default timeout?

Is the common practice is to dedicate a separated task for transmission, or to configure the socket with any option?
Vxworks 6.9, kernel mode.
Thanks